# Error with code in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have this code but I get this error:

```
application: not a procedure;
  That procedure can expected to be applied to arguments
    given: '(8 1 2 3 4 5)
    arguments .:
```

I tried to fix it but still no result.

This function should return a new list inserting the elements of the list called "listas" on the respective positions contained in the list called "indices".

```
(define (insertar posicion elemento lista)
  (cond ((= posicion 0) (cons elemento lista))
     (else (cons (car lista) (insertar (- posicion 1) elemento (cdr lista))))
  )
)

(define multi-insertar (lambda (lista listas indices)
                         (if (not (eq? (length listas) (length indices)))
                             "Numero de indice no es igual a numero de listas a ingresar"
                             (if (= 1 (length indices))
                                 (insertar (car indices) (car listas) lista)
                                 ((insertar (car indices) (car listas) lista)
                                  (multi-insertar lista (cdr listas) (cdr indices))
                                 )
                              )
                         )
                        )
)
```

Comment: See where you have `((insertar ...`? `insertar` returns a list, so you'll eventually be trying to apply the list as a procedure, hence the error

Comment: Yes, just get rid of that parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably wanted to do is this:

```
(define (multi-insertar lista listas indices)
  (if (not (eq? (length listas) (length indices)))
      "Numero de indice no es igual a numero de listas a ingresar"
      (if (= 1 (length indices))
          (insertar (car indices) (car listas) lista)
          ;; only the following branch is changed
          (insertar (car indices) (car listas)
                    (multi-insertar lista (cdr listas) (cdr indices))))))
```

So now `multi-insertar` inserts all elements using `insertar` starting from the end of `lista`.

Comments:

`elementos` would be a better name for `listas`

This would only work as expected, when the indices are in decreasing order. Compare the following two examples:

```
> (multi-insertar '(a b c d e f) '(x y z) '(1 3 5))
=> (a x b c y d e z f)
> (multi-insertar '(a b c d e f) '(z y x) '(5 3 1))
=> (a x b y c z d e f)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the 6. and 7. line of `multi-insertar` you have:

```
(let ((operator (insertar (car indices) (car listas) lista))
      (argument (multi-insertar lista (cdr listas) (cdr indices))))
 (operator argument)) ; operator must be a procedure for this to work!
```

I have put the two expressions in a `let` to make it more readable what you are doing.  What the error says is that the value of `operator` isn't a procedure but the list `(8 1 2 3 4 5)` and `('(8 1 2 3 4 5) argument)` makes no sense to the evaluator.

However code like this does make sense, since here the variable `operator` is a procedure:

```
(let ((operator (if (< x 1) * /))
  (operator x 10)) ; we either divide or multiply by 10.
```